# How to repair kernel error pcieport AER: P pcieport: device [8086:a110] error status/mask=00000001/00002000

Tags: kernel, 19.10, error-handling

I have installed Ubuntu 19.10, everything was working fine until i tried to install steam app.
These following errors constantly recur:

`kernel pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)`

`pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER:   device [8086:a110] error status/mask=00000001/00002000`

`pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER:    [ 0] RxErr`

Bios version: E16J5IMS.11D
on PE60-6QE

`lpci`
[image: sudo lspci]

 `lspic -tv` [image: lspci -tv]

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lspci` and `sudo lspci -tv` and `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the make/model of your computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**AER**

AER (Advanced Error Reporting) shows a correctable error on device 1c.0. According to `sudo lspci -tv` the misbehaving device *might* be your wireless 3165 card. Check to make sure you have the latest driver and firmware for this device.

Otherwise, if you see no outward signs of operational issues, and after scrutinizing `/var/log/syslog*`, you can do this to quiet the noise...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` # edit this file

Locate the string "quiet splash" and change it to "quiet splash pci=noaer".

`sudo update-grub` # update GRUB

`reboot` # reboot the computer

**Memory**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: I already upgraded firmware for intel card, but i think it might actually be the hardware issue, because it happened even in windows, i was systematic cut in use every few hours, suddenly i had disconnected internet connection. 5-7 times a day. Thanks for confirmation and solution to squelch the noise :)

Comment: @UMR If the problem also occurs in Windows, then it's time we tested the memory. Please see the update in my answer. Report back.

Comment: It happened in Windows before, now I only use Ubuntu/Debian. Funny, on Debian i don't have any problems even with kernel or drivers (logs show sudden voltage shortage for intel wireless), but here on Ubuntu many interesting things occur. I have tested my new memory recently after warranty service - everything is perfect. I am sure its Intel hardware fault. (when plugged rj45 no kernel issue ever during Ubuntu runtime). Thanks for thinking out of box.

Comment: Thank you very much)