# ubuntu doesn't boot up it show me error message "rtl187123be 0000:01:00.0 AER: Error of this agent is reported first"

Tags: boot, dual-boot

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu on my laptop it worked well.
I am using dual boot Ubuntu 22.04.3 and Windows 10, it does boot Windows fine but when I select Ubuntu it doesn't boot up instead it shows me this error:
[image: error]

I tried going to recovery mode but it didn't work out is dual boot the issue?

Comment: The recovery mode that didn't work: I don't know the actual status of your system, which kernel you have on... and specifically which actions you took. So. Please, try again but this time applying the solution approved [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1213973/how-to-repair-kernel-error-pcieport-aer-p-pcieport-device-8086a110-error-st) Recovery mode - part 2: Since you are there (and the above solution didn't work) you might want to check for some system update (the our favourite apt update/upgrade) BIOS: Looking on-line many people with a very similar issue solved by upgrading their bios